# Visual Studio 2015 vs Visual Studio '15'

Tags: visual-studio

I installed VS 2015. I was trying to learn C# 7.0 features. I did not get them. But then I came to know that these features are in Visual Studio 15 Preview (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/03/30/visual-studio-15-preview/).

The version for Visual Studio 2015 in the **Help => About** section is: **14.0.25431.01 Update 3**

It is confusing about what is this Visual Studio '15' and what is Visual studio 2015 with version 14 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 is version 14.x.

Visual Studio '15' is version 15.x, and was the code name for what is now called Visual Studio 2017.

The year and the version number do not usually align - they did with Visual Studio 2010 (10.x), which was a fluke.